# How to skip a column in datagridview when the tab key is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there a way to skip certain columns when the **tab key**/**arrow key** is pressed?

Suppose I have three columns (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`). Say I was on `col1`, I would want to skip `col2` when the tab key is pressed.

How can I do this?

Comment: DataGridView and DataGrid are two distinct controls.  Clarify that. Also choose a "wpf" tag for DataGrid or a "winform" tag for DataGridView.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in **CellEnter** event.

Try this：

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {           
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "col2")
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        } 
    }
```